# How to replace a specific word from String in Java

Tags: java, android

How to replace "{{customer}}" from this string "Congrats {{customer}}, you become the potential winner of auction" with "xyz".

Thanks in advance,
Suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
 String string = "Congrats {{customer}}";
 String newValue = string.replace("{{customer}}", "xyz");

  // 'string' remains the same..but 'newValue' has the replacement.
 System.out.println(newValue);
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get? Note that the string is only replaced on the 'newValue' variable..not on the 'string' variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` method on the `String` object to do this. Since `String` is immutable it will return a new object instance with the replaced text. Example:

```
String myString = "Congrats {{customer}}";
myString = myString.replace("{{customer}}","John");
System.out.println(myString);
```

Output:

```
Congrats John
```

See also the [String javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for many more useful utility methods.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a mustache template.

See https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java

Typically, in your case:

```
HashMap<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
scopes.put("customer", "xyz");

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache mustache = mf.compile(new StringReader("Congrats {{customer}}, you become the potential winner of auction"), "example");
mustache.execute(writer, scopes);
writer.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using resources, you can use method like this:

```
String customer = "Joe Doe";
String textHello;

textHello = String.format(getString(R.string.hello_customer), customer);
```

where `hello_customer` is your string resorce strings.xml.

strings.xml part should look like this:

```
<string name="hello_customer">Congrats %1$s, you become the potential winner of auction with \"xyz\".</string>
```